# Building a project with library dependency prevents cleaning

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

Windows 10, gradle 4.1, build tools 27.0.2, gradle plugin 3.0.1.

I have an application `app`, with a dependency to `android-faq-bot`.

If i do `./gradlew.bat clean` after a successful build, i get the following error:

```
$ gradlew.bat clean app:compileJenkinsDebugSources
app: 'annotationProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1'.
Configuration 'testCompile' in project ':android-faq-bot:app' is deprecated. Use 'testImplementation' instead.
:clean
:android-faq-bot:clean UP-TO-DATE
:app:clean
:android-faq-bot:app:clean FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android-faq-bot:app:clean'.
> Unable to delete file: C:\Users\onion\boeg\android-faq-bot\app\build\intermediates\intermediate-jars\debug\classes.jar
```

Running

```
handle C:\Users\onion\boeg\android-faq-bot\app\build\intermediates\intermediate-jars\debug\classes.jar

Nthandle v4.1 - Handle viewer
Copyright (C) 1997-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

java.exe           pid: 2160   type: File           F38: C:\Users\onion\boeg\android-faq-bot\app\build\intermediates\intermediate-jars\debug\classes.jar
```

I tried disabling all plugins, disabling `dexInProcess`.
No go, only option is to kill the gradle daemon.
I tried attaching the `https://github.com/kohsuke/file-leak-detector` javaagent to see where the file is opened, but i cannot get it to work on windows. 
I also tried forcing a GC from jconsole, hoping that a non-reachable File would finalize and releasing the FD. But no.

Any suggestions?